# Why are my objects frozen?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a version of Space Invaders in Python, but for some reason, none of my Aliens or the player is popping up. They do show up if I press space, but there, they're just just frozen. It happened after I added my collision code, but I don't know why it's happening. Help would be appreciated. This is my code:`

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
import time
#Setting up pygame
pygame.init()
shooting = False

goingright = 1
keys = [False,False,False,False]
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])
font = pygame.font.Font(None,50)
#Creating class for player
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,[0,255,0],[int(self.x),int(self.y),int(self.width),int(self.height)],0)
    def move(self):
            if keys[1] == True:
                self.x -= 1
            elif keys[3] == True:
                self.x += 1

            if self.x < 0:
                print(self.x)
                self.x = 0
            if self.x > 500 - self.width:
                print(self.x)
                self.x = 500 - self.width
    def shoot(self):
        return
class Bullet():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
    def update(self,y_amount = 5):
         self.y -= y_amount
         return
    def draw(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,[0,255,0],[int(self.x),int(self.y),10,50],0)


class Alien():
    def __init__(self,x,y,goingright,dead):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.goingright = goingright
        self.dead = dead
    def draw(self):
         self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,[0,255,0],[int(self.x),int(self.y),25,25],0)

    def move(self):

        if self.goingright == True:
            self.x += 0.1
            if self.x > 500 - 25:
                self.y+=25
                self.x = 475
                self.goingright = False
        elif self.goingright == False:
            self.x -= 0.1
            if self.x < 0:
                self.y+=25
                self.x = 0
                self.goingright = True




bullets = []        
aliens = []  


#Creating a player

player = Player(200,450,40,20)
for i in range(100,800,75):
    aliens.append(Alien(i,100,True,False))


#Main Loop
while True:

    #Background
    screen.fill([0,0,0])
    #Letting Player move
    player.move()
    #Drawing Player
    player.draw()
    #Updating screen

    #Checking for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        #Checking for quit   
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            #Checking for keys
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                keys[0] = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                keys[3]=True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullets.append(Bullet(player.x, player.y))



        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                keys[3]=False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                shooting = True
                shooting = False
                c = 0














    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw()
        bullet.update()
    for alien in aliens:
        alien.draw()
        if alien.dead == False:
           alien.move()
    for alien in aliens:

        for bullet in bullets:    

           if alien.x < bullet.x + 10 and alien.x + 25 > bullet.x and alien.y < bullet.y + 50 and 25 + alien.y > bullet.y:
               pygame.display.flip()
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) must be called to refresh the scene. Since you are doing that only when a narrow set of conditions is satisfied, the screen is not getting refreshed even though the aliens, bullets and player positions/states are being updated.

if i am not mistaken the narrow set of conditions is collision detection and should be updating the status of the alien to dead. You'll also need to move the `flip` call into the main `while True:` loop (python scopes are tab sensitive)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't notice I moved it to the For Loop